# Can I access the value of a derived-class member in a function running in a std::jthread from which I derive?

Tags: c++, multithreading, derived-class

The following code works (i.e., it prints `42`) on all systems I have tried, but I am not sure it is generally valid. My concern is that `my_int` is not yet fully constructed and initialized by the time it is read - or am I wrong?

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

struct MyThread : std::jthread
{
    MyThread() : jthread([this] {
        std::cout << my_int << std::endl;
    }) {};

    std::atomic_int my_int = 42;
};

int main()
{
    MyThread();
    return 0;
}
```

I find that

> Threads begin execution immediately upon construction of the associated thread object

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) but I am not 100% certain that means the thread begins execution as soon as the `jthread` base object is constructed (which I expect to be correct), or as soon as the `MyThread` object is constructed (which I hope is correct).

Comment: standard library types are generally not designed to be inherited from. std::jthread for example [does not have a virtual destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread). You should make your jthread a member of MyThread, and then you can place your int before the thread and it will be ok. (There is a nice quote on OO : whatever you think inheritance is probably not the solution)

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks for confirming my expecations. "You should make your jthread a member of MyThread, and then you can place your int before the thread and it will be ok" - that's what I did in the meantime :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior.

> I am not 100% certain that means the thread begins execution as soon as
> the jthread base object is constructed

No, that means that the new thread begins executing at some unspecified point after `jthread` is constructed.  The only guarantee is that the `jthread` will be constructed when the thread begins execution.

Here, in the original execution thread, after the `jthread` base class gets constructed, then construction begins of the derived class and its members. There is no guarantee, whatsoever, that `jthread`'s execution begins after the derived class's members are constructed.